# Describe DB2 stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer tool to connect to both the Oracle and IBM DB2 databases. I am able to see the stored procedures for Oracle DB in the Connections panel when I open the Oracle connection. But for the DB2 connection, It is not displaying anything in the connections panel when I expand the connection.

So, I tried to see the Stored procedure definition in the DB2 using queries.
I tried the following ways, but nothing worked.

When I fire the `select * from SYSIBM.SYSPROCEDURES;` query, I got error saying

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SYSIBM.SYSPROCEDURES, DRIVER=3.64.82
```

When I fire `SELECT ROUTINENAME FROM SYSCAT.ROUTINES;`, I got error saying

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SYSCAT.ROUTINES, DRIVER=3.64.82
```

When I try `-DISPLAY PROCEDURE;`, I got error saying

```
SQL Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=-;<ERR_STMT> <WNG_STMT> GET SQL SAVEPOINT HOLD FREE ASSOCIATE, DRIVER=3.64.82
```

Can some body help me how to get the Stored procs in DB2.

Comment: what version of DB2 and on what platform, what JDBC driver are you using, and what version of SQL Developer? I'm guessing you're on an unsupported combo...

Comment: I am using IBM DB2 9.7, and the JDBC driver db2jcc4.jar and SQL developer 3.2.09

Comment: Are you sure you have rights to those tables -- this could happen if you don't have access.

Comment: DB2 9 on LUW should be ok in SQL Dev, your copy of SQLDev is fairly old...it might be more the db2 driver or like what @RadhakrishnaGorenta said

Comment: @Hogan, Thank you for the sugession. The connection actually works and I can successfully execute SQL statements afterwards, however autocompletion and browsing the list of tables doesn't, which renders the tool pretty useless.

Comment: @RadhakrishnaGorenta - The security model on DB2 is complex - it is possible to execute statements and not be able to browse these system tables/views.  It is even possible for you to only have rights to view **single rows** in these tables you want to access.  *You should talk to your DBA about what access you have been granted*